# Deserializing an Object that has been serialized using ObjectOutputStream's writeObject method

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization, objectinputstream, objectoutputstream

If you serialize an Object using ObjectOutputStream's writeObject method, is the only way to deserialize it through ObjectInputStream's readObject method? Can you call ObjectInputStream's other read methods?

Comment: If what's in the stream is an Object, then `readObject` is the right way to read it.  If it's a primitive, then you'll need one of the other read methods.  Is that what you're asking?

Answer (score 0):

Items in object streams are tagged. If you try to use the wrong `readXXX()` primitive to read them you will get an `EOFException`. The only methods you can use to read a written object are `readObject()` and `readUnshared().` You can always read the raw bytes with the `read()` methods of course, but you'll probably make it impossible to use any of the `readXXX()` methods afterwards, by moving to an arbitrary position in the stream.